# Python import statements breaking print value headed to php code

Tags: php, python, web, import, shell-exec

I am making a website with php and a coworker is providing a python script that my php code will execute through shell_exec(). His python script uses a print statement to send the output needed to my php code. We noticed through the creation of a simple test python script, no printed value were returned when the following import statements were included...

```
import pypyodbc
from collections import OrderedDict
import argparse
import pymysql
```

but when these imports were excluded, we were able to get output. Any ideas as to why this may be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you execute the script from command line?

Comment: The coworker was able to execute the script from the command line. Albeit he was executing it from his own location. I copied the python script over to my working directory and according to him all those import statements are fairly standard and shouldnt require any extra work. I guess the answer to this question that I am expecting will involve something about the file location mattering. But me having no python experience, I know nothing about that.

Comment: Try executing it from the machine from which the PHP script is calling it, and include the errors in your question. Also, can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: the test python script is as follows

Comment: import sys
#import argparse
import time
#import pymysql
import datetime
#import pypyodbc
#from collections import OrderedDict
import traceback
import os

def main():
 name = "Success3.txt"
 open(name, 'w')
 print "success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()

Comment: hard to parse python code without any newlines or whitespace :P, can you update your original question with that script?  Also, should be `if __name__ == "__main__"` otherwise it'll never run anything